# 403 Forbidden Error when sorting MySQL Columns from Within PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, debian, http-status-code-403

[image: Error in processing request, Error code: 403, Error text: Forbidden]

I keep getting that error message every single time that I try to sort any column from inside PhpMyAdmin.

Here is a list of my current server architechture:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 - Debian 9.1
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
PhpMyAdmin Version information: 4.6.6deb4
nginx/1.10.3
PHP version: 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 
Running Debian 9.3
```

I can't seem to see anything related to the 403 error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` nor in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as root user? Do you have ALL privillages? Check all privileges if not.